# как создать Оконное приложение ,модель MVC

Tags: java

у меня есть код консольной программы,где все коллекции реализовывал сам.Теперь нужно из консольного приложения сделать оконное.Я разработал каркас в scenebuilder ,а как связать это все?И получается,что код консольной программы это Model?а каркас это View?И что будет Сontroller?

Comment: Очень грубо говоря модель - ваши данные, представление - интерфейс отображающий данные из модели, контроллер - программная прослойка реагирующая на действия пользователя в интерфейсе и изменяющая данные в модели. Судя по куцому описанию - сцена будет представлением, ваши данные из старой консольки - моделью, а "как связать это всё" - контроллером. По крайней мере могут таковыми стать.